# Collatz conjecture, Tao-Collatz remainder and mod n.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, collatz-conjecture, open-problem

Collatz conjecture is equivalent to
$n\times 3^{k} = 2^{ak+1} - TCR$
where, for me, $k$=odd steps, and $ak+1 $=even steps.
Note that total steps = k +( ak+1) steps. Some numbers have the same total steps, but $k$ steps and $ak+1$ steps are different because it is unique for every n.

Even numbers are $\equiv \pmod{2}$ remainder 0 and $\equiv\pmod{3}$ remainder 0,1,2 .
Odd numbers are $ \equiv \pmod{2}$ remainder 1 and $\equiv\pmod{3}$ remainder 0,1,2.

Professor Terence Tao talks about $3^{k-1}*2^{a1} + 3^{k-2}*2^{a2} + ... +2^{ak }$  and the study of his properties to take any advance in the solution on his post about Collatz conjecture. Let´s call it Tao-Collatz remainder, $TCR$ for me, I think that

$2^{ak+1}\equiv TCR \pmod{n}$

The gcd ($2^{ak+1}$, n) =1 , so there exists just 1 solution for this congruence.And $2^{ak+1}$ – TCR is a multiple of $n$. Effectively for each power of 2,  $2^{x}> n\times 3^{k}$ exist 1 solution with the form $2^{x}-r$ .This simple question based on the Euclidean algorithm of division may not be strong enought for a demostration. We know that

$n^{i}\equiv r_{i}\pmod{n}$

When $3^{0}\rightarrow TCR= 0$ , $3^{1}\rightarrow TCR= 1$ , $3^{k}\geq  2\rightarrow TCR = 3^{k-1}*2^{a1} + 3^{k-2}*2^{a2} + ... +2^{ak }$
 And

$3^{0}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ , $3^{1}\equiv 3\pmod{n}$ , $k\geq 2
,3^{k}\equiv \chi \pmod{n}$

If $2^{ak+1}\chi \equiv TCR \pmod{n}$ and $3^{k-1}\equiv \chi \pmod{n}$, where $\chi $ is the remainder, is the solution, and the Euclidean algorithm always ends, ¿is it the probe that the Collatz conjecture is true?

What is the solution to this congruence?

Comment: Does $ak$ mean $a\times k$? What is "the properties of (8)"? Moreover, the "$...$" in "3^k-1*2^a1 + 3^k-2*2^a2 + ... +2^ak" is not clear.

Comment: Sorry. I do not do it better, I accept edit suggestion. Please forgive me. ak+1 is a power of 2. For example 7 * 3^5 = 2^11 - 3^4 * 2^0 - 3^3 * 2^1 - 3^2 * 2^2 - 3^1 * 2^4 - 3^0 * 2^7. (8) in Professor Tao´s post, in his blog, about Collatz conjecture is the Tcr, for me.

Comment: I have edited the question with new advances.

Comment: Are you referring to his 2011 blog post here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/ ?

Comment: I previously posted on here about the Collatz function being a Euclidean division with remainder. While I can't follow completely just yet, it looks like you're saying something similar.

Comment: Now I am studying the conjecture from the modular exponentiation, the calculation of the exponent by the discrete logarithm and the Collatz function as a one-way function. Respect to Professor Terence Tao's post, despite being from 2011, I think it is the reference more close to a solution of the conjecture, as far as I can know. As for our reminder, which always exists, it must be the difference between the power of 2 and n * power of 3, although something is missing that gives us the correct solution, because for each power of 2 there is a remainder that fulfills that condition.

Comment: In my last comment on Terence Tao´s blog I commented how, visually, through a matrix of n as a function of the number of odd steps k, it is seen that it is impossible to have another cycle more than 1,2,4,1.

Comment: I as a lay person am thinking that probability or two consequitive odds is zero whereas probability of two consequitive evens is NOT zero and since even means halving of the value, the sequence eventually will reduce to 1. Would I be correct in following that line of reasoning?